# How to interpret the stationary solutions to the Fokker-Planck equation if there is no diffusion?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

For a stochastic differential equation of the form

$$ dX_t = f(X_t) dt + \sqrt{2\Gamma} dB_t, \ \   X_0 = Z$$

we have that the density of $X_t$,  $p(t,x)$, fulfills the Fokker-Planck equation

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x,t) = \\-\sum_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}  \left(f(x)p(t,x)\right) + \sum_i \sum_j \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} \Gamma_{ij} p(t,x).$$

Since this was taught to me in a stochastic analysis class, where the focus clearly is not on the deterministic case, we never discussed the case when $\Gamma=0$. However, now that I think about it, the formula should of course also hold in this case.
But in this case we would have that
$$X_t = \Phi_t(Z),$$
where $\Phi$ is the vector field associated to the ordinary differential equation that results.
Thus, my question would be, how to interpret the stationary solution in this case. Do we actually reach this solution, in the sense that the process forgets about the initial distribution? Clearly this will not always be the case, for example when we have $Z=x_0$ for constant $x_0$.
But also another possible counterexample that comes to my mind would be the following:

$$f\begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}.$$

In this case one can see that a centered gaussian, $$p(u) \propto -\exp\left(-\frac{||u||^2}{2}\right)$$
with $u = \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y\end{pmatrix}$, is a stationary solution. Now since the dynamics only rotate the vector, I would guess that we only can achieve a Gaussian if we already start with a Gaussian, $Z \sim p$.

So, in general, is a stationary solution $p$ only actually reached if $Z\sim p$ or are there other possibilities?

Comment: You seem to think that when there is diffusion, the distribution of the process always converges to a stationary distribution.  Why?  Whether or not there is diffusion, in general, all we can say about a stationary distribution is that if $X_{0} \sim p$, then $X_{t} \sim p$ for all $t > 0$.  The question of asymptotics (i.e. Does the distribution of $X_{t}$ converge to $p$ if the distribution of $X_{0}$ is near $p$?) is non-trivial.

Comment: @PeterMorfe you are right, I think I was implicitly assuming that it would be the default case in the stochastic setting that the (distribution of the) process converges to the stationary distribution. Do you maybe have a ressource that discusses this question of asymptotics?